# Можно ли отключить gzip сжатие только для определенных клиентов( которые заходят с определенно ip) в nginx

Tags: nginx, настройка, gzip

Как можно отключить gzip сжатие для определенных клиентов(ip адресов)?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов.

Вариант 1 - с использованием [GEO](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) модуля

```
geo $disable_gzip {
  default 0;
  1.2.3.4/32 1;
  2.3.4.5/32 1;
  3.4.5.6/32 1;
}

server {
  if ($disable_gzip) {
    gzip off;
  }
}
```

Вариант 2 - использовать HttpAccessModule

```
server {
    if ($remote_addr ~ "^(1.2.3.4|2.3.4.5)$") {
        gzip off;
    }
}
```

Как по мне - предпочтительнее 2-й вариант, т.к. не используются регулярные выражения, да и проще для обслуживания.